# Hide HTML tags from textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on email system in my project(PHP/MySql). In my email forward form I have a text area where I'm including the following data as gmail and yahoo is doing.

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: <testfrom@yahoo.com>
Date: Mon, Jan 9, 2014 at 10:48 PM
Subject: Order Confirmation
To: testto@gmail.com
```

I'm using `echo "\n";` for line breaking in the above data. When I forward this data in email, It send as one row instead of sending as the above format. Can anyone help me how to send it in exactly the same format.

Note : I try to user `<br>` for line breaking but in that case it send `<br>` also in email.

Comment: You could use `nl2br`. How are you creating the mail message and the mail itself.

Comment: @putvande I just echo all detail of the email inside Textarea. User can edit that area

Comment: @Zub I'm not using any editor. I use simple textarea

Comment: I know. But If the user puts a break in the textarea that will be an `\n`.

Comment: `<br>` is for HTML-based Email. If you want to use `<br>` you would need to use `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` in your headers. For more info on this, visit the PHP.net Website => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know hot send HTML email but I want to hide <br> in textarea.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but explain, how do you know that it sends data in one row? Where do you view the result?

Comment: Can you show us your code? There are too many factors at play. Otherwise, we'll just keep commenting, and stands at being long, then SO will close the question because of being too chatty.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/nl2br) for your message. This will convert all `\n` to `<br/>`.

Something like:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
mail('email@example.com', 'subject', nl2br($message));
```

Answer (score 0):

My only assumption that new line symbols are present in an email, you just don't see them.

For example, if you create php script:

```
<?php
echo "hello \n world";
```

and open it in a browser, you will not be able to view new line, because browser doesn't handle `\n` symbol as line break.

You will only see line breaks if you view the source of the page (by hitting `CTRL+U` in Chrome and Firefox, don't know about other browsers).